# How do I get permission to read/write access to database located in Resources inside sandboxed app?

Tags: database, cocoa, resources, entitlements, sandbox

I have database in the MyApp.app/Contents/Resources folder. I want at least to read data from it in the sandboxed app.

Now I have a lot of "deny file-write-data /Users/user/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/DB/app_db.db" in the Console.

I can't use com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write because I don't want to rely upon end user location of the app.

In spite of warnings in the Console my app is working. Is there any entitlement to give access or I should to copy my db to the container during first start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even reading from a db can require the DB to write to create locks etc., and you don't have a lot of control of that (you may have some depending on the db). Just follow your own intuition - copy the db on first run to your container.

Also file a radar, it can't harm.